# Jquery Mobile: style grid to validate HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, validation

In my web site, I'm using Jquery mobile and I need to use a grid to align buttons in the center of every cell:

```
|   [BUTTON]   |   [BUTTON]   |   [BUTTON]   |
```

My code is

```
<div class="ui-grid-c" align="center">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
       [button code]
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
       [button code]
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
       [button code]
    </div>
</div>
```

But if I use the `align` attribute in the `div` I get an HTML5 validation error.

So my question is, how ho I set a style to obtain that graphical result?

Comment: there is nothing like align="center" for div. U may use text-align="center"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want them aligned beside one another or on top of one another (but in the middle), but adding `text-align:center;` to the `ui-grid-c` div should apply itself to the divs underneath and will force buttons (`<input>` or `<button>`) to be centred because they are inline elements.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/cuLMq/1/) a JSFiddle example.

**Edit**
Also, if you want them to go across, you'll want `float` the inner divs and specify widths for them (`33%` should be good if you only have three). See my example.

And here's the code:

```
.ui-grid-c {
    text-align:center; 
}
.ui-grid-c > div {
    width:33%;  /*Remove this if you don't want them in a line*/ 
    float:left; /*Remove this if you don't want them in a line*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;">
----Conent------
</div>
```

This will put even margins on both sides of the div.